# Open SWF game into Unity

Tags: android, ios, flash, unity-game-engine, webgl

I have too many games (700+) built in flash (*.swf) but as you know these files can not be opened in iOS browsers.

Is there any way to run my flash games on iOS devices?

Is there any way to convert these SWF game files to Unity and export the project from inside Unity?

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is like asking about converting a Lamborghini to apple sauce. Games made with Flash and Unity are based on two ***very*** different technologies and there is no way to easily convert between the two.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)**

> Is there any way to convert these SWF game files to Unity and export
>   the project from inside Unity?

You can run Flash games on IOS with the help of Flash-enabled web browser apps like Photon.
 
But I don't think there's a way of converting Flash `.swf` files into Unity format.

**(2)**

> Is there any way to run my flash games on iOS devices?

You can use Adobe Flash (now called Adobe Animate) to create an iOS app by using their Actionscript 3.0 language (similar to Java and C#).

The AS3 language has a `stageWebView` API, which can load html pages and has the *Flash Player* plugin built-in to the API's webkit browser..